# using a url redirect + concatenation classic asp

Tags: javascript, asp-classic, ip, blacklist

We are on a shared hosting plan at godaddy and the site was developed entirely in classic asp. There is some "recommend a product  to a friend" functionality which sends out an email using cdo. This functionality, which triggers an email containing the link to product on the website, has stopped working and we think because of some spam/blacklist, and hoping there is a programming workaround as getting through to godaddy is not working!

The IP 45.40.165.35 and the malicious redirect on the shared hosting plan which got us into trouble and for which we have nothing to do is "http://bauerwhitetails.com/rx.html"

One work around which sort of works is to use a url redirect in the msg body to do away with the website url however this takes the user to the home page rather to the product! Is there a smarter way to do this or should I use another smtp provider?!

```js
 
<%

Dim objNewMail, sBody

Set objNewMail = Server.CreateObject("CDO.Message")
objNewMail.From = Request.Form("Your email address")
objNewMail.Cc = Request.Form("Your email address")
objNewMail.To   = Request.Form("Email to")

objNewMail.Subject = "Interesting Property Recommended by " & Request.Form("Your Name")
sBody = Request.Form("Your Name") & " wants to show you an interesting property." 
sBody = sBody & "<br>Click the following link <a href=http://www.websitehere.com> <b> here </b> </a> to search for the Property Ref: <b>" & Request.Form("pid") & "</b><br>"

If Request.Form("Message") <> "" Then
sBody = sBody & "<br><br>Message from " & Request.Form("Your Name") & " : " & Request.Form("Message")
End If
sBody = sBody & "<br><br>Thank-you!"

objNewMail.HTMLBody = sBody

objNewMail.Configuration.Fields.Item _
 ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusing")=2

objNewMail.Configuration.Fields.Item _
 ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserver")="relay-hosting.secureserver.net"

'Server port
objNewMail.Configuration.Fields.Item _
 ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserverport")=25 

objNewMail.Configuration.Fields.Update

objNewMail.Send
```

Comment: What redirect you talk about? You mean change the URL of your site to something else?

Comment: I think you've answered the question yourself.  If your emails are being sent from a blacklisted server then you need to find an alternative SMTP provider, and it would make sense to use one which requires authentication. NB If you decide to use Office 365 then cdo prefers port 25 to port 587 even if you are using authentication

Comment: I agree with the above. I moved off Classic ASP a few years ago, but we had similar issues with shared platforms and how mail is handled. In our example we had an issue sending email to a recipient with the same domain name as the website itself. It could have been sorted, but for speed and also in an attempt to create separation of functions we moved all website mail services to an alternative external provider. In your case above you would tweak your script to suit the mail providers SMTP settings and probably add in a username and password.